# Real data not found in R/exams

Tags: r, r-exams

I am trying to develop an exam based on the results of a logit model fitted to a real data set. I try to load the data set, fit the model, and include some variables extracted from the model using the `r varname` syntax.

I first developed a small example using artificial data generated within the exercise. That worked fine and this is the corresponding Rmd file:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}    
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble(y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.6), x1 = rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100))

# randomize exams
nsize <- sample(50:150, 1)
sampled_dat <- sample(1:nrow(d), nsize, replace = TRUE)
fd <- d[sampled_dat, ]

fmodel <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = fd, family = binomial("logit"))
```

Question
========    
`r nrow(fd)`

```{r}
summary(fmodel)
```
    
Choose the correct answer. 

Answerlist
----------
* sol1  `r nrow(fd)`
* sol2
    
Meta-information
================
exname: bdvDeviance
extype: schoice
exsolution: 10
exshuffle: TRUE
```
````

This worked as expected when launching

```
elearn_exam <- c("ess3.Rmd")
set.seed(1234567)
exams2nops(elearn_exam, n = 2, language = "en",
           institution = "U", title = "Exam",
           dir = "nops_pdf", name = "BDV", date = "2018-01-08", duplex = FALSE)
```

However, this is the analogous exercise loading a real data set:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}    
load("d.Rdata")
# randomize exams
nsize <- sample(180:250, 1)
sampled_dat <- sample(1:nrow(d), nsize, replace = TRUE)
fd <- d[sampled_dat, ]

logitModel <- glm(Adopted ~ CultArea + Trained + LabRice+ Education + ExtContact, data = fd, family=binomial("logit"))    
```

Question
========    
`r nrow(fd)`

Choose the correct answer.

Answerlist
----------
* When adding  variables, the deviance did not change. The variables did not bring some useful information. 
* sol2 `r nrow(fd)`

Meta-information
================
exname: bdvDeviance
extype: schoice
exsolution: 10
exshuffle: TRUE
```
````

This time, I get the following error:

```
> elearn_exam <- c("ess4.Rmd")
> set.seed(1234567)
> exams2nops(elearn_exam, n = 2, language = "en",
+            institution = "Uu", title = "Exam",
+            dir = "nops_pdf", name = "BDV_R", date = "2018-01-08", duplex = FALSE)
Quitting from lines 14-35 (ess4.Rmd) 
Error in nrow(fd) : object 'fd' not found
```

I do not understand what the problem is in the second case. Apparently, the `fd` variable is not found when including it in `r fd`. The problem does not come from the regression because that works fine when knitting the Rmd file.

Comment: My guess is that the first code chunk fails because `d.Rdata` is not found -> hence `fd` cannot be created -> hence `fd` cannot be inserted. If the `d.Rdata` file is in the same directory as `ess4.Rmd` then including `include_supplement("d.Rdata")` before the `load("d.Rdata")` should do the trick. Let me know if it does, then I'll write up a proper answer. If not, provide more details about the data file.

Comment: Thank you Achim for pointing out to this command that I had overlooked. It is now working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just wrote a full answer...oh, and you already accepted it, thanks! I also modified your question slightly (especially the title) so that others who have the same problem can hopefully find it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example using the real data set just loads the corresponding data file via `load("d.Rdata")`, assuming that it is in the current working directory. However, when using any `exams2xyz()` interface, the exercises are processed in a temporary directory in order not to clutter the user's workspace. Hence, the `d.Rdata` file is not found in that directory and consequently cannot be loaded. And because of this problem, the `fd` object cannot be created and inserted. In short, the `r fd` code is working fine, the problem is loading the data.

To avoid this problem, you must either specify the full absolute path to your data file in `load("/path/to/d.Rdata")` or you need to copy the data to the temporary directory before loading it. For the latter, there is the convenience function `include_supplement()` that copies supplementary files to the temporary directory. By default, it takes them from the directory the exercise resides in. So you simply need to add:

```
include_supplement("d.Rdata")
```

before loading the data file. Note that when the file is not in the exercise directory itself but some sub-directory you can add the argument `recursive = TRUE`. Then sub-directories are searched recursively.

Comment: I have tried to do the same, it seems to work but creating many exercises I get a warning for each one of them saying "The following files are found more than once, first match used".

Comment: Presumably you search a folder and its subfolders recursively and several subfolders contain a file with the same name.